# React How can I receive the 3h rain foreact from openweathermap (Identifier directly after number error)

Tags: reactjs, openweathermap

I am new to programming and I don't have the necessary basics.
I am trying to get the data for rain from OpenWeatherMap and I still get the error:

> Parsing error: Identifier directly after the number.

The first two examples are not working. I can only stringify the object. Can you please suggest what is the correct way of typing ".3h"?

```
{test.list.map((item, key) => <p key="{key}">{item.rain.3h}</p>)}

{test.list.map((item, key) => <p key="{key}">{item.rain.["3h"]}</p>)}

{test.list.map((item, key) => <p key="{key}">{JSON.stringify(item.rain)}</p>)}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is because variables are not supose to start with a number, therefore, dot notation will come up with an error. The second example might work by removing the last dot, just like this:

```
test.list.map((item, key) => item.rain['3h'])
```